# Custom Syntax Highlighting with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am interested in creating a custom syntax highlighter that can be used in a Sphinx environment. Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Background

Sphinx (http://sphinx-doc.org/) internally uses Pygments (http://pygments.org/) as a syntax highligher. Pygments supports adding custom syntax highlighter (lexer) as described here http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/.

### Example usage

I would try to define a new custom lexer in Pygments and initialize that new custom lexer in the `conf.py` sphinx configuration file. A small example that should get you started:

```
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer
from pygments import token
from sphinx.highlighting import lexers

class BCLLexer(RegexLexer):
    name = 'MYLANG'

    tokens = {
        'root': [
            (r'MyKeyword', token.Keyword),
            (r'[a-zA-Z]', token.Name),
            (r'\s', token.Text)
        ]
    }

lexers['MYLANG'] = BCLLexer(startinline=True)
```

Comment: I tried to get the lexer working as you suggested, but sphinx is telling me it does not find the lexer. Could you give a short example of how to include the lexer into the conf.py file?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Since it is your answer, do yo want to add a MWE or is it ok, if I create an answer with a MWE?

Comment: @MrZ: what is MWE? I would prefer to extend this answer if something is missing, but be free to create a new one if you think that is better solution.

Comment: @MrZ: thx. Like I said, whatever you prefer, be free to extend or create a new one.

Comment: I extended. I just wasn't sure if SO would accept large changes as `edits`.

Comment: `startinline` appears to do nothing here. It appears to be an option for the `PhpLexer` class, but this keyword argument is not defined for `RegexLexer`.